# NoSuchElementException java.lang.Scanner

Tags: kotlin

I have no idea what the error is, I am having a hard time adapting to this language, any help thank you very much.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Packing.<init>(Packing.kt:100)
    at PackingKt.main(Packing.kt:7)
    at PackingKt.main(Packing.kt)
```

My code:

```
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val input = Scanner(InputStream.nullInputStream())

    val packing1 = Packing(input)
    val packing2 = Packing(input)
    val packing3 = Packing(input)

    var total = 0
    var min = 0
    val combinations = ArrayList<String>()

    for(a in 1..3){
        for(b in 1..3){
            for(c in 1..3){
                //here is a piece of code
            }
        }

        combinations.sort()
        println("${combinations.get(0)} $min")
    }
}

class Packing {

    var brownBottles = 0
    var greenBottles = 0
    var clearBottles = 0

    constructor (input : Scanner){
        brownBottles = input.nextInt() //this is the line 100
        greenBottles = input.nextInt()
        clearBottles = input.nextInt()
    }
}
```

The idea is to enter values by console that initialize the variables of my objects.

Comment: why are you passing `InputStream.nullInputStream()` to `Scanner`? Maybe you need ```Scanner(System.`in`)```?

Comment: I tried with System.in but I got an error, I will try with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use

```
val input = Scanner(System.`in`)
```

If you enter 9 integers in the console the initialization of the Packing objects should work.
The nullInputStream() makes no sense to me. It's not possible to read from the console with that.

The combinations list is empty so it throws an exception accessing it here

```
println("${combinations.get(0)} $min")
```